# Transfer PHP/MySQL to new webserver, all links come up hashtags

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

For general safety reasons, I would like to have a duplicate machine that runs our internal database.  Keep in mind, we are not using VMs.  The internal database is MySQL and it is interfaced via html interface written mostly with php and some javascript when needed.  Everything is based on the Fedora lineage of distros.

I built the new server, linked up MySQL, copied the web structure and used Navicate to transfer the data. Here is where I am a bit baffled and need some guidance.  The first page of our internal website is a list of our active in-house jobs.  The name of each job is a drill-down to the job detail page.  On the functional website, this link works fine, on my recreation, when I click on a job, I am not redirected to the job detail drill down.  Instead, I go to an internal URL that ends with a hashtag # symbol at the end. The page doesn't redirect, it just adds the hashtag to the end of the URL that it is at. It goes from 192.168.1.254/jobtable.php to 192.168.1.254/jobtable.php# . On the server that is working, the page briefly goes dark, then the job detail screen is displayed.  On the working server, it does not add the hashtag at the end of the URL.

This was coded by hand. Unfortunately our programmer has moved on. Do you know what is breaking down?  Is this javascript or php?  If I am guided in the right direction, I can try to fix the broken bridges...

Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: I'm a little unclear.  You are being redirected to a different page, correct?

Comment: The hashtag shouldn't be much of a problem. But we need to know whether its ran by something handcoded, a framework, an cms or something else?

Comment: this could be well anything from bad data in your database, a typo in your codebase, or an error with some kind of javascript work. it all depends on how the page is being formed, where the link is stored, and what is being retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hashtag at the end of a link would suggest that there is some JavaScript involved. Usually the link structure would look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">Link Text</a>
```

If JavaScript function is no longer there `doSomething`, clicking the link will just display the hashtag. Not sure what browser you are using but you should have some sort of console where you can see errors, and a JavaScript error should tell you what JS function is missing.

I would download FireBug for FireFox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ and fire it up and look at the 'Console' log to see what errors might come up when you click the link

Comment: So I followed the Firebug console suggestion and found that the error was here:  <?php foreach($_GET as $t => $v) {$$t = $v;} ?> .  This was located in a file called userform.js .  As soon as I commented it out, the page seemed to work, i.e. it passed to the job detail drill down as expected.  It seems like that bit of php in the javascript was causing the error.  Here is my next question:  why doesn't it cause an error on the current production server?  The script and file/folder structures are identical on both machines. Thanks for the help.  Now I need to figure out why that php line...?

Comment: really hard to say, the servers have to be configured exactly the same, for example some servers will not run php code that starts with `<?` instead of `<?php` it looks like the code you commented out is looking for some query variables, perhaps there is some .htaccess redirecting requests differently on your new server?